# Automate Array Modifier

Tags: modifiers

I am looking to use blender as shelf planning tool and I want to automate the array modifier.
So when I place the packaging onto a plane, it should automatically fill the plane (like that: [image: Packaging])

Is there any way to do that, or do I have to do it manually every time?

Thank you for your help :)
BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options is to use "fit type - fit curve".
You can fit the curve to your "shelf" or add some geometry to the curve so that it becomes the shelf.

[image]

Another option is to add a "driver" to the "fit type - fit length - length" parameter which will determine the length of the shelf.

[image]

The driver might be more complex than that, for example it might determine the size of the object's parent and fill it automatically if parenting is considered as "putting a package on the shelf".

Comment: Hey :) thanks for the help - the option with "fit curve" seems to be the option for us. Thank you very much for the help